# How can I create a sliding size selector with HTML?

Tags: html

How can I create something similar to the image using only HTML5?

```
__________
s  m  l  xl
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: An `<input type=range>` would be a start :)

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is simplest solution.

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="3" step="1">
</div>
<div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:35px">S</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:35px">M</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:35px">L</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:35px">XL</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Improvement suggestions: Use a flexbox container to keep things in alignment rather than hard-coded sizes; use CSS classes rather than inline styles.

Comment: thank you!!!! Nice!!!!